# Link DLL in Borland C++ compiler

Tags: c, dll, borland-c++

I use freecommandlinetools compiler bcc32. I need to use third party dll in my program. I'd prefer not to call `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`, but rather to link the dll in my program to call the dll functions directly.

```
#include "somelibrary.h"

int main() {
  somefunction(); // defined in somelibrary.dll
}
```

I see unresolved externals in attempt to compile. How to convince the linker to link with the somelibrary.dll?

Comment: The functions in the dll need to be exported with [__declspec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d.aspx), are they?

Comment: Yes, they are. I have no issue using them in MinGW compiler, I just don't know the borland ways.

Comment: First use dumpbin /EXPORTS your.dll to see the exported symbols from the dll. Next, write a .def file for it and follow the steps listed here: https://support.microsoft.com/kb/131313/en-us Then, link your program against the import library and you can avoid LoadLibrary() and GetProcAddress().

Comment: Ah, freecommandlinetools contains `implib.exe` that creates the import library. But I still struggle using it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must create a .lib in order to link the dll directly.
Supposing your dll is user32.dll :

```
implib -a -c -f user32.lib user32.dll
```

Will create user32.lib with all the symbols of user32.dll. Then link your project with user32.lib instead of user32.dll.

You can use the impdef.exe command to see the symbols exported by the dll. If these symbols already start with an underscore '_', you can omit the -a in the implib command.

Comment: Ah, the `-a` switch was the root of all evil! Excellent!